# How make image link open by click instead of edititng?

Tags: jira, confluence

I have created jira task with link to image like that:

```
!https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/15/22/55/wolf-3818354_960_720.jpg|height=250!
```

So now it looks like that:

[image]

But when I click on image it is not opened. Instead jira switch to task editing mode:

[image]

Is there a way to make image opened without download and attach it to the task manually?

Comment: Can you apply a hyperlink to the image? That's what you'd usually do in HTML / BB-Code.

Comment: Do you mean by this? Use `<a>` in wiki? Could you please add en example of it?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me (put the image inside the link).
My JIRA version is 7.12.1.

```
[!https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/15/22/55/wolf-3818354_960_720.jpg|height=250!|https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/15/22/55/wolf-3818354_960_720.jpg]
```

Note that "Edit description on clicking on it" is the standard JIRA behaviour.